# Get page parameter in a form without users editing them

Tags: php, forms, parameters

Hi i'm having a problem where in my form I put the page parameters. However users can change this how can I make it so that users cannot change this?

Here is my form

```
<form name="comment" method="post" action="/news.php?page=shownews&id=<?php echo $pid; ?>">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" size="40" maxlength="30">

      <label>E-mail:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" size="40" maxlength="60">

      <label>Your message:</label>
      <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="79" maxlength="500"></textarea>

      <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit">
</form>
```

So they shouldn't be able to edit the $pid.

Comment: any way, you can validate these parameters before doing anything else

Comment: Users can edit HTML and send their own id to your page.
To avoid users from taking advantage of that, you will need to have server side validations to check the id being posted.

Comment: How can I check it server side?

Comment: Is the pid the same as the page a use is looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action attribute is completely arbitrary in HTML. It means, if you leave it, it will default to the current page. Therefore, If you want users to submit to current page, just leave out the action i.e:

`<form name='comment' method='POST'>` should be enough.